# Selectivly publishing artefacts based on source changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a repository that contains,

- Application Source Files (src)
- Terrafrom IAC Files (tf)

Folder Structure:

```
.
├── azure-pipelines-prod.yml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Whoa.API
│   ├── Whoa.Core
│   ├── Whoa.Data
│   ├── Whoa.Services
│   └── Whoa.sln
└── tf
    ├── dev.tfvars
    ├── main.tf
    ├── resources
    └── variables.tf

7 directories, 6 files
```

I want to publish Two Artifacts,

- Source Changes (when files in src/ changes)
- Terrafrom Changes (when files tf/ changes)

How can I conditionally push these artifacts only if a change only took place on it's corresponding folder?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add PowerShell script to your CI build. Example to copy changed files to the artifact directory:

```
$targetfolder = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)" + "/"

function CopyFiles{
    param( [string]$source )

    $target = $targetfolder + $source

    New-Item -Force $target
    copy-item $source $target -Force
}

$changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR HEAD^ HEAD .

if ($changes -is [string]){ CopyFiles $changes }
else
{
    if ($changes -is [array])
    {       
        foreach ($change in $changes){ CopyFiles $change }
    }
}
```

In your case, use `src` and `tf` folders in the script:

- Source Changes

  ```
  $changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR HEAD^ HEAD src
  ```
- Terrafrom Changes

  ```
  $changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR HEAD^ HEAD tf
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I believe that `git diff` command was what I was searching for, I should be able to use that to conditionally publish the artifacts.